# StructureMap Argument out of range by Generic Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, structuremap, structuremap3

I have a strange problem with following structuremap configuration example:

**IReturnValue**

```
 public interface IReturnValue {
 }
```

**IService**

```
 public interface IService<T> where T : IReturnValue {
    void Execute();
  }
```

with two implementations:

**ServiceA:**

```
public class ServiceA : IService<IReturnValue> {
   public void Execute() {
     //do something 
   }          
}
```

**ServiceB**

```
public class ServiceB : IService<IReturnValue> {    
   public void Execute() {
     //do something
   }  
}
```

**Registry**

So now I register ServiceA and ServiceB in the main method: (note the order!)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   IContainer container = new Container();
   container.Configure(c => c.For<ServiceB>().Use<ServiceB>());
   container.Configure(c => c.For<IService<IReturnValue>>().Use<ServiceA>());
 }
```

**Problem:**

During the registration of ServiceA this exception throws:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: instance 'Example.ServiceA' with ReturnType 
Example.ServiceA cannot be cast to Example.ServiceB
```

No InnerException and no other errors.

**Registry changed order**

When I change the order of the registration, everything works and I can use the services.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IContainer container = new Container();
        container.Configure(c => c.For<IService<IReturnValue>>().Use<ServiceA>());
        container.Configure(c => c.For<ServiceB>().Use<ServiceB>());
}
```

Can someone explain me why structuremap has a problem with the first registration example?

- StructureMap: 3.0.5.130
- .Net 4.5

Comment: Why are you registering `ServiceB`? the container would be able to resolve classes even without registering them.

Comment: Yes this is correct. But i think that the registration of ServiceB should be also possible and the exception makes no sense for me.

Comment: I stumbled on the same limitation but for me this is a showstopper. Did you ever find out a solution?